# On Solaris, how do you mount a second zfs system disk for diagnostics?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, zfs

(Cross posted from Stack Overflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539938/on-solaris-how-do-you-mount-a-second-zfs-system-disk-for-diagnostics))

I've got two hard disks in my computer, and have installed Solaris 10u8 on the first and Opensolaris 2010.3 (dev onnv_134) on the second. Both systems uses ZFS and were independently created with a zpool name of 'rpool'.

While running Solaris 10u8 on the first disk, how do I mount the second ZFS hard disk (at /dev/dsk/c1d1s0) on an arbitrary mount point (like /a) for diagnostics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running under Solaris 10u8 you won't be able to mount zpools created on a new OpenSolaris build. (snv_134).  Since S10u8 and snv_134 are using different ZFS On Disk Pool Versions (IIRC [15](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/15) and [22](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/22) respectively) only when running OpenSolaris will you be able to access both volumes.  ZFS is backwards, but not forwards compatible.  Also having multiple pools with the same name ('rpool) on the same physical system isn't supported.  You should rename one of them.

To mount the second 'rpool' volume, do the following while booted into OpenSolaris:

```
# zpool import
Find the cXtXdX disk corresponding to your S10 rpool
# format -e
Find the UUID string corresponding to your cXtXdX disk
# zpool import <UUID> notjustrpool 
Imports the other rpool and renames it to 'notjustrpool'
```

You can also specify a mountpoint with `-m  /mnt/point/` after your zpool import statement, but once you've renamed it, it'll just mount as /notjustrpool.  Sub-pools that have their own non-nested mountpoints (like rpool/export) may conflict with your existing mountpoints, so once you've imported the pool you'll have to `zfs set mountpoint=/export2 rpool/export` or whatever.    Note, you'll  have to update your grub menu.lst to reflect the pool name change if you still want to boot the renamed rpool.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to do this so if you have any valuable data I suggest that you backup things before proceeding.  I believe you have to use the `zpool import` command.  Check the zpool manpage for more details on the import and export commands.

Also note that the version of ZFS on OpenSolaris is newer and most likely not compatible with Solaris 10U8.  So you'll probably only be able to do this from OpenSolaris and not the other way around.  You should also be careful not to run a `zpool update` command on the Solaris pool's version.  It will suggest that you do this when you run any zpool command when it detects an older version of ZFS.

Comment: Also take care here b/c it's likely that both zfs zpools are named rpool.  I believe one of the options on zpool import allow you to give the imported pool a new name.